# Find an onto and one to one (1-1) function from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,1,2\}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Find an onto and one to one (1-1) function from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0,1,2\}$

---

I thought about the inverse of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x-2}$,
but I am not sure if it's 1-1 and onto, also I can't find the inverse.

What's the idea for this kind of problems, I can't  see it.

(tags maybe not correct)

Comment: can you find a one to one onto function from the positive integers to the positive integers greater than 3?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think  $3n+1$ does the job

Comment: If you search, you can find a bijection from the reals to the reals with one point missing. Through translations and composition you can construct the function you seek.

Comment: Nothing says your function must be continuous.  f(x) = x if x is not a positive integer or zero, f(x) = x+3 otherwise.

Comment: @DougM oh I made a mistake this is not onto

Comment: @JohnDouma I only one a fiction like that on the complex plane , $e^z$ but I will search it up

Comment: The function cannot be continuous because a connected set is being mapped to a disconnected set.

Comment: No. Sending $n$ to $3n+1$ never hits 101 or 102, because they aren't of that form. It's way easier than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x \;\; &\text{ if } x \not\in \mathbb{N} \\ x + 3 &\text{ if } x \in \mathbb{N} \end{cases}$$

Works

( $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,\dots\}$ )